# DeviceOrientation Event on React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Im learning how to use device orientation sensor in React Native app through https://www.w3.org/TR/orientation-event/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Detecting_device_orientation.

My App.js:

```
const App = () => {
    window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", onOrientationChanged,true);
    function onOrientationChanged(event) {
        
        var absolute = event.absolute;
        var alpha = event.alpha;
        var beta = event.beta;
        var gamma = event.gamma;
        console.log(beta);
    }
        return (
    <>
        <ScrollView
                contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic">
                <Text>kfkasdfasd</Text>
        </ScrollView>
    </>
  );
};
```

Running this results in:

`TypeError: window.addEventListener is not a function. (In 'window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", onOrientationChanged, true)', 'window.addEventListener' is undefined)`

I couldnt google anyone having the same problem, so I am confused as how to solve this when I followed documentation and did not add anything extra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The window object does not exist in React Native.

Check out the useDimension hook from react-native-hooks https://github.com/react-native-community/hooks#usedimensions

or if you want more details checkout https://github.com/react-native-sensors/react-native-sensors